# React Hooks Exhaustive Deps suggest infinit loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I get the following esLint error

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'time'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) (ESLint)`

If i follow the suggestion, and provide `time` as part of the dependency array I will get an infinite loop because the `setTime` prop will keep updating the `time` prop.

```
const TimeValidator = ({
    time,
    setTime
}: {
    time: Time;
    setTime: (time: Time) => void;
}) => {
    const [newTime, setNewTime] = useState(time);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Save the duration from the time property
        const duration = time.end - time.start;
        if (newTime.start > time.end) {
            // Use the duration to create a valid time object, where "start" < "end"
            setTime({ start: newTime.start, end: newTime.start + duration });
        } else if (newTime.end < time.start) {
            // Use the duration to create a valid time object, where "start" < "end"
            setTime({ start: newTime.end, end: newTime.end + duration });
        } else {
            setTime({ ...time, ...newTime });
        }
        // react-hooks/exhaustive-deps suggests "time". But this will lead to
        // infinite update loop
    }, [newTime, setTime]);

    return <TimeChooser time={time} setTime={setNewTime} />;
};
```

[Link to expo snack - Try to update the time in dependency array](https://snack.expo.io/@rcknti/useeffect-infinite-loop)

The idea is that the parent pass down a `time` object and a callback to update the time object. The `TimeValidator` pass the `time` object down to the child - `TimeChoser`, but overwrites the callback. If the updated `time` from the child of `TimeValidator` is not valid, the `TimeValidator`  will try to update the `time` object, so that `start` is always less than `end`.

Is there a good pattern on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: in deps why are you passing setTime? Have you already tried newTime only and not the set?

Comment: @WahabShah Eslint, react-hooks/exhaustive-deps recommends i pass [`newTime`, `setTime`, `time` ]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes es-lint will have some exceptions in genuine usecases. In these cases you have to use `// eslint-disable-next-line` comment.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 ----
 // eslint-disable-next-line
},[newTime, setTime])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You think this is genuine usecases? I am a bit afraid of not taking the `time` prop into consideration, because the closoure of my `useEffect` might have a reference to an old `time` prop, and ` setTime({ ...time, ...newTime });` could potentially update the `time` object with old values. I know it is not so obvious from my example. If have a more complex time object in my business code, with name of the person, id etc

Answer (score 0):

I think i can convert my useEffect into a useCallback instead:

```
const TimeValidator = ({
    time,
    setTime
}: {
    time: Time;
    setTime: (time: Time) => void;
}) => {
    const updatedTracking = useCallback(
        (newTime, updateTime) => {
            // Save the duration from the time property
            const duration = time.end - time.start;
            if (newTime.start > time.end) {
                // Use the duration to create a valid time object, where "start" < "end"
                updateTime({
                    start: newTime.start,
                    end: newTime.start + duration
                });
            } else if (newTime.end < time.start) {
                // Use the duration to create a valid time object, where "start" < "end"
                updateTime({ start: newTime.end, end: newTime.end + duration });
            } else {
                updateTime({ ...time, ...newTime });
            }
        },
        [time]
    );

    return (
        <TimeChooser
            time={time}
            setTime={time => updatedTracking(time, setTime)}
        />
    );
};
```